# Transferring CDI qualifier to injected field

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, java-ee-7

I'm working on a Java EE 7 application in a Wildfly 8.2 container which contains some entites that exist in two data sources. Example:

I have a jar with `Setting` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Setting {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String value;

    getters/setters...
}
```

and a bean which has a couple of methods for retrieving and saving this entity from database via criteria query:

```
@Stateless
public class SettingRepository {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Setting findByName(@NotNull String name) {
        logger.trace("Getting setting by name: name=" + name);
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Setting> cq = cb.createQuery(Setting.class);
        Root<Setting> table = cq.from(Setting.class);
        cq.where(cb.equal(table.get(Setting_.name), name));

        TypedQuery<Setting> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
        List<Setting> results = query.getResultList();
        Setting setting = null;

        if (results.size() > 0)
            setting = results.get(0);

        logger.trace("Got setting: " + setting);
        return setting;
    }

    ...
}
```

I wan't to provide `EntityManager` and `Logger` instances via @Producer in a application which includes this jar in classpath like this:

```
@Produces @DataSource1 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu1")
private EntityManager entityManager1;

@Produces @DataSource2 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu2")
private EntityManager entityManager2;

@Produces
private Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    return LogManager.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
}
```

**Is there any way to configure SettingRepository at injection point and tell it to use specific entity manager (`@DataSource1` or `@DataSource2`)?**

Similar to this:

```
@Inject @DataSource1
private SettingRepository settingRepository;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route I chose to take is this one:

I created a qualifier

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER })
public @interface DataSource {
    @Nonbinding DataSourceName value() default DataSourceName.D1;
}
```

Note the `@Nonbinding` annotation which tells container I don't have to specify this parameter when annotating producer method (especially this one, sine I can implement generic producer, more on that later) or injection point.

And `DataSourceName` enumeration, which simply lists all data sources:

```
public enum DataSourceName {
    D1, D2
}
```

I also changed `SettingRepository` implementation and added a public initialize method.

```
@Dependent
public class SettingRepository {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void initialize(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that `EntityManager` is no longer injected by container.

When I wan't to inject `SettingRepository`, I simply decorate it with this qualifier like so:

```
@Inject @DataSource(DataSourceName.D1)
private SettingRepository settingRepository;
```

All I need now is to define a producer for `SettingRepository`:

```
@Stateless
public class TestResourcesForSettings {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu1")
    private EntityManager entityManager1;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu2")
    private EntityManager entityManager2;

    @Inject
    private SettingRepository settingRepository;

    @Produces @DataSource
    public SettingRepository produceSettingRepository(InjectionPoint ip) {
        DataSource annotation = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(DataSource.class);

        if (annotation.value() == DataSourceName.D1)
            settingRepository.initialize(entityManager1);
        else if (annotation.value() == DataSourceName.D2)
            settingRepository.initialize(entityManager2);

        return settingRepository;
    }
```

And voila, I can use two data sources with one repository implementation (note: data sources have to be XA). **If anyone finds any problems with this choice please tell me.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes !

In fact you have done all the hard work already as far as producer methods and qualifiers are concerned :-) All you need to do is use your qualifier (@DataSource1 etc) on the injected EntityManager instance

```
@Inject @DataSource1
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

This will ensure that JPA entity manager attached to persistence unit 'pu1' is injected by the container.

Comment: Thank you, but the first time I know which data source I'm going to need is  at `SettingsRepository` injection point not `EntityManager` injection point. So i was wondering if there is a way of "transfering" qualifiers from parent injection point (`SettingsRepository`) to child injection point (`EntityManager`) or is it better to use parameters on each method.